# Using jhipster framework to configure mongodb prompt not authorized

Tags: mongodb, jhipster

I used scaffolding to generate a new microservice，then I made the following configuration for mongodb:

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: DEBUG
    io.github.jhipster: DEBUG
    com.fzai.fileservice: DEBUG

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8761/eureka/

spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
    include:
      - swagger
      # Uncomment to activate TLS for the dev profile
      #- tls
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: true
      additional-exclude: static/**
    livereload:
      enabled: false # we use Webpack dev server + BrowserSync for livereload
  jackson:
    serialization:
      indent-output: true
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: 42.193.124.204
      port: 27017
      username: admin
      password: admin123
      authentication-database: fileService
      database: fileService
  mail:
    host: localhost
    port: 25
    username:
    password:
  messages:
    cache-duration: PT1S # 1 second, see the ISO 8601 standard
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  sleuth:
    sampler:
      probability: 1 # report 100% of traces
  zipkin: # Use the "zipkin" Maven profile to have the Spring Cloud Zipkin dependencies
    base-url: http://localhost:9411
    enabled: false
    locator:
      discovery:
        enabled: true

server:
  port: 8081

# ===================================================================
# JHipster specific properties
#
# Full reference is available at: https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/
# ===================================================================

jhipster:
  cache: # Cache configuration
    hazelcast: # Hazelcast distributed cache
      time-to-live-seconds: 3600
      backup-count: 1
      management-center: # Full reference is available at: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/management-center/3.9/manual/html/Deploying_and_Starting.html
        enabled: false
        update-interval: 3
        url: http://localhost:8180/mancenter
  # CORS is disabled by default on microservices, as you should access them through a gateway.
  # If you want to enable it, please uncomment the configuration below.
  cors:
     allowed-origins: "*"
     allowed-methods: "*"
     allowed-headers: "*"
     exposed-headers: "Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count"
     allow-credentials: true
     max-age: 1800
  security:
    client-authorization:
      access-token-uri: http://uaa/oauth/token
      token-service-id: uaa
      client-id: internal
      client-secret: internal
  mail: # specific JHipster mail property, for standard properties see MailProperties
    base-url: http://127.0.0.1:8081
  metrics:
    logs: # Reports metrics in the logs
      enabled: false
      report-frequency: 60 # in seconds
  logging:
    use-json-format: false # By default, logs are not in Json format
    logstash: # Forward logs to logstash over a socket, used by LoggingConfiguration
      enabled: false
      host: localhost
      port: 5000
      queue-size: 512
  audit-events:
    retention-period: 30 # Number of days before audit events are deleted.
oauth2:
  signature-verification:
    public-key-endpoint-uri: http://uaa/oauth/token_key
    #ttl for public keys to verify JWT tokens (in ms)
    ttl: 3600000
    #max. rate at which public keys will be fetched (in ms)
    public-key-refresh-rate-limit: 10000
  web-client-configuration:
    #keep in sync with UAA configuration
    client-id: web_app
    secret: changeit
```

An error occurred while I was running the project:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongobee' defined in class path resource [com/fzai/fileservice/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorized on fileService to execute command { find: "system.indexes", filter: { ns: "fileService.dbchangelog", key: { changeId: 1, author: 1 } }, limit: 1, singleBatch: true, $db: "fileService" }' on server 42.193.124.204:27017
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at com.fzai.fileservice.FileServiceApp.main(FileServiceApp.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorized on fileService to execute command { find: "system.indexes", filter: { ns: "fileService.dbchangelog", key: { changeId: 1, author: 1 } }, limit: 1, singleBatch: true, $db: "fileService" }' on server 42.193.124.204:27017
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:706)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:695)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:462)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:406)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:695)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:179)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.FindIterableImpl.first(FindIterableImpl.java:198)
    at com.github.mongobee.dao.ChangeEntryIndexDao.findRequiredChangeAndAuthorIndex(ChangeEntryIndexDao.java:35)
    at com.github.mongobee.dao.ChangeEntryDao.ensureChangeLogCollectionIndex(ChangeEntryDao.java:121)
    at com.github.mongobee.dao.ChangeEntryDao.connectMongoDb(ChangeEntryDao.java:61)
    at com.github.mongobee.Mongobee.execute(Mongobee.java:143)
    at com.github.mongobee.Mongobee.afterPropertiesSet(Mongobee.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1830)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

But in my other simple springboot project, I used the same configuration, which can run and use successfully:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: springboot1
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: 42.193.124.204
      port: 27017
      username: admin
      password: admin123
      authentication-database: fileService
      database: fileService
```

This is the user and role I created:

```
{
    "_id" : "fileService.admin",
    "userId" : UUID("03f75395-f129-4273-b6a6-b2dc3d1f7974"),
    "user" : "admin",
    "db" : "fileService",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "fileService"
        },
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "fileService"
        }
    ],
    "mechanisms" : [
        "SCRAM-SHA-1",
        "SCRAM-SHA-256"
    ]
}
```

I want to know what's wrong.

Comment: I found a project named [jhipster-sample-app-mongodb](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-mongodb),by comparing the code, I found a class named databaseconfiguration,It has one more bean,when I annotate it, the project can run successfully.